# How to deal with index error and value error?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a problem.This dataset has two categorical columns. Whenever I execute `labelencoder_y` it gives me `IndexError: too many indices for array` and whenever I run last `onehotencoder` it gives me `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'No'`. Although I am not facing any problem with x values. How to deal with it? The dataset is below

```
Site Name,Per Article,Per Song,Per Hour,Per Test,Per Survey,Per Minute,Pakistan
Listverse,100,0,0,0,0,0,Yes
Playlist Push,0,12,0,0,0,0,No
TranscribeMe,0,0,18,0,0,0,Yes
IntelliZoomPanel,0,0,0,10,0,0,No
Italki,0,0,12,0,0,0,Yes
Vindalle Research,0,0,0,0,3,0,No
Rev,0,0,0,0,0,2,Yes
QuickRewards,0,0,0,0,5,0,No
```

And this is my code:

```
#Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('sheet.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-7].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 7].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X= LabelEncoder()
X[:,0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

labelencoder_y = LabelEncoder()
y[:,0] = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y[:,0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
y = onehotencoder.fit_transform(y).toarray()
```

Comment: I have update the question with dataset. Now check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there was too much indexing. Stripping it all out, the encoding works without error

```
labelencoder_y = LabelEncoder()
y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()
y = onehotencoder.fit_transform(y).toarray()
```

Comment: How does this reshape work? What is the meaning ```-1``` as a row?

Comment: It is a transposition required by the one hot encoder (which expects 2d arrays)